# Weird error in Sitecore user manager

Tags: sitecore, user-management

I am having this weird error in sitecore user manager. 
I get this error as soon as i open user manager
I can't assign users to roles.

Can anyone please help ?[image]

Thanks in advance.

P.S > Just in case it's not visible properly : http://www.flickr.com/photos/24436387@N00/9030219859/lightbox/

Comment: Could it be that Remains is an extra field you have added to the users at some point?

Comment: Do you use custom membership provider? Try to cleanup core database from Sitecore Desktop > Control Panel > Databases

Comment: Have you modified the membership providers section of the web.config at all?

Comment: What version and rev of Sitecore?

Comment: @Holger - The users are coming from an external source. There's not field in the user called Remains. I bet this field is related to pagination.

Comment: @WesleyLomax Yes. I have added the connection string to pull the users from outside source (It's not AD user) and modified membership provider. But I dont unserstand how it's affecting Pagination of the user manager. Even if it is how do I change it/correct it? I'm a bit surprised that sitecore did not handle this exception very well thus giving us no clue.

Comment: @MarkUrsino 6.5 rev 121009 and updating is not an option as per client requirement.

Comment: @MarasMusielak -- good point. I haven't tried that. :) .. Will give it a try and post the out come.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the solution. I was using a third party provider (connector to salesforce) which was pushing campaign members to sitecore. And there was a bug in that API that was giving sitecore the wrong total null but only users.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Found [this](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%206/ReleaseNotes/KnownIssues%20Recommended/AutomaticDataBind=True%20Setting%20Influences%20User%20Manager%20Behavior.aspx) sdn post as well, refers to paging and databinding errors in the user manager should be fixed in your version of Sitecore though.

Although may give you something else to investigate.

Comment: thanks for the response. I applied the second workaround .. unfortunately that did not work either.